# How do I transfer reputation points from one Stack Exchange site to another?

Tags: support, reputation, rep-transfer

I have earned points on Stack Exchange for Database related. How do I transfer those points to dba.stackexchange?

Answer (score 8):

## You can't.

Your reputation for each site is earned for *that site* respectively.

Answer (score 7):

> Reputation is a rough measurement of how much the community trusts
>   you; **it is earned by convincing your peers that you know what you’re
>   talking about.** The more reputation you earn, the more privileges you
>   gain and the more tools you'll have access to on the site - at the
>   highest privilege levels, you'll have access to many of the same tools
>   available to the site moderators.

If you know programming, does it mean you will be able to talk about bicycles?

Comment: OP specifically asked about transferring reputation from the same domain. The bicycle analogy is a bit of a strawman.

Comment: @bruglesco - The communities are separate for a reason, if they were similar enough to warrant reputation transfer between them, they should be a single community.  Doesn't matter if we are talking about Serverfault and SuperUser, or Workplace and Law.

Comment: @Ramhound I am not arguing that it should be an added feature. But the OP specifically wants the reputation they earned under the `database` tag to transfer to dba. Bicycles are a strawman.

Comment: "If you know programming, does it mean you will be able to talk about bicycles?" ⇒ Why would this be a basis for *preventing* me of fixing a 1-character typo in a bicycle post when I'm more than trusted on stackoverflow?

Comment: @MarkJeronimus There is a certain community on each Stack Exchange site, and you should leave all edits and corrections to their users.

Comment: Then why does it ask new users to make more edits to get to the required 6 characters? This sounds like reverse logic. If you don't know the subject you may make contextual edits but not typo edits.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is, **you can't.** Reputation is specific to each individual site and marks how thorough your knowledge is on the site's subject. While you do earn the association bonus to get past the basic new user restrictions, you have to gain reputation on each specific site to gain the privileges that heavily affect the site's content.

Answer (score 3):

You simply can't:

My reputation on X site is on X site,

My reputation on Y site is on Y site,

There is no way to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be different...

You can "effectively" transfer reputation by applying your database expertise to questions on dba.SE.

OTOH, you already have higher rep there than SO, so I don't think it's something you should spend any time worrying about.